# Sort ADF table created using ArrayList

Tags: sorting, oracle-adf

In my use case I have created table using arrayList not using collection model.

So how can I enable sorting in my ADF table?

Comment: You might take a look at http://soadev.blogspot.com/2013/05/sortable-collectionmodel.html.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a method that sorts the array, you can then call it from the actionListener for the sort event on the column.